# What happens when you're really plagued by a popular song but you have no weasels to pop?

Tags: fallen-london

One of the many dangers of Fallen London - or at least Mahogany Hall - is that sometimes, when a song gets stuck in your head for too long, your weasels start exploding. I've been trying to avoid this by simply not keeping any (weasels are expensive, m'kay), instead only buying them when I need to.

Have I *weaseled* my way out of this terrible fate, or have I simply doomed myself in another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have no weasels when that infernal song takes its toll, then [some poor passerby's weasel pops](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/A_danger_to_your_weasels). You'll pick up some Scandal from being the instigator.

It's your choice when you're getting highly plagued by a popular song: buy/steal a weasel specifically to watch unspeakable things happen to it, or take Scandal instead.